# Texturing curves in blender

Tags: 3d, game-design, textures, blender, 3d-modeling

Im making a tree in blender with the sappling add-on,  i've already textured the leaves, i want to know how to texture the trunk with a bark texture. Im using cycles render.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Side note: you might have better luck posting your question on https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

There are two methods you could use to do this. The first would be to make a procedural material. The wood texture on your tree would be generated as it is being rendered. The geometry node would be handy for this:
[image: Demonstration of the geometry node]

Red varies with x, green with y, and blue with z. You can use this to generate various textures:

[image: Demonstration of the bands texture]

The second way to do it would be to convert the curve into a mesh. Select your curve and press alt+c to do so:
[image: Demonstration of conversion from curve to mesh]

You can then proceed to unwrap it like a regular mesh, then apply a wood texture to it:
[image: A bad UV unwrap job demonstrating that the curve can be used like any old mesh.]

Hope this helps, and good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ive made about 10 prefabs with leaf textutes and everything except for the bark texture, now i can finally finish the asset

Comment: No problem! By the way, since you have 15 reputation, could you vote up my answer?